# I want to be able to toggle filled star icon (fas fa-star) with unfilled star icon (far fa-star)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    item1
    <i class="far fa-star" onClick="star(this)"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    item2
    <i class="fas fa-star" onClick="star(this)"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    item3
    <i class="far fa-star" onClick="star(this)"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    item4
    <i class="fas fa-star" onClick="star(this)"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

This js works but as everyone can see this looks ridiculous and doesn't feel like the best way to solve my problem.

```
function star(recevingStarInfo){
    $(this).hasClass("fas")?"": recevingStarInfo.classList.toggle("fas");
    $(this).hasClass("far")?"": recevingStarInfo.classList.toggle("far);
}
```

I tried:

```
function star(recevingStarInfo){
        $(this).hasClass("fas")? recevingStarInfo.classList.toggle("far"): recevingStarInfo.classList.toggle("fas");
```

But when ever I click filled star(fas fa-star) it gets replaced by unfilled **square**. I also tried to use `.removeClass('')` and `.addClass('')` as well as `.toggleClass('far fas')` nothing works.

FYI I can't use id on list because I am using filled and un-filled star on other parts of the code outside of the list.

If my description upto this point is still unclear, I want to be able to click on star icon and change it form filled to unfilled and vice versa.

Feel free to use jQuery or vanilla js and I am just learning js, if possible use simple code to solve my problem.

Comment: Side note, if you are doing to use the `classList.toggle()` method, you might as well use the `classList.contains()` method for the ternary and avoid jQuery in the inner logic all together.  Otherwise you're just weirdly mixing methodologies.  Imho

Comment: did my snippet below help to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will helps:

```js
$('.fa-star').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fas far');
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="images/favicon" type="image/png" rel="icon">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
</head>




<body>

  <ul>
    <li>
      item1
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
      item2
      <i class="far fa-star"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
      item3
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
      item4
      <i class="far fa-star"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>




</body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.fa-star').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fas far');
})
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="far fa-star"></i>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `toggleClass()` to alternate classes on an element.

```js
function star ( icon ) {
  $(icon).toggleClass('fas far');
}
```

```css
.far { background-color: red; }
.fas { background-color: blue; }

.far, .fas {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    item1
    <i class="far fa-star" onClick="star(this)"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    item2
    <i class="fas fa-star" onClick="star(this)"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    item3
    <i class="far fa-star" onClick="star(this)"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    item4
    <i class="fas fa-star" onClick="star(this)"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```